# Asp.net help It gives error in home page only

Tags: asp.net

i am new to asp.net.

I have uploaded a site in ftp. except default.aspx remaining pages working. when i navigate to home page i.e Default.aspx it shows an error

Server Error in '/' Application.
The resource cannot be found.
Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly.

Requested URL: /Default.aspx

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:2.0.50727.3607; ASP.NET Version:2.0.50727.3082

Please help. I am stuck here itself.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You probably have forget to upload all your site. Check if you have upload the default.aspx.cs, then check again what you have upload and if they are full uploaded and they not 0 size or corrupted.